# Is it possible to use andStubReturn without replay() in EasyMock

Tags: testing, easymock

Well the question is the same as the title.

Example of what I am aiming at,

```
Order order = createNiceMock(Order.class);
Products products = createNiceMock(Products.class);
expect(myDomain.getOrder()).andStubReturn(order);
replay(myDomain);
expect(myDomain.getOrder().getProducts()).andSubReturn(products);
```

I think this is a pretty nice way to handle my test domain. The thing is that I don't want to use replay to be able to do the `myDomain.getOrder()`. Is it possible to do this without the replay?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
Order order = createNiceMock(Order.class);
Products products = createNiceMock(Products.class);
expect(myDomain.getOrder()).andStubReturn(order);
expect(order.getProducts()).andSubReturn(products);
replay(myDomain, order);
```